# pulling a date from the selected item of a Kendogrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with a KendoGrid object where one of the columns I have is called Birthdate. I need to be able to pull a DateTime value from the selected item in that list.

Here is what I have tried

```
    var grid = $( "#MainRosterGrid" ).data( "kendoGrid" );
    var ageDOB = grid.select().data.Birthdate;
```

im pretty sure the second part of that line is wrong but I am very inexperienced with the KendoGrid. 
this is all running in a Javascript function and I am having a really hard time testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to depend on column positioning and directly get the value by the column name, you should do:

```
// Get reference to the grid
var grid = $( "#MainRosterGrid" ).data( "kendoGrid" );
// Get Selected row
var sel = grid.select();
// Get item data corresponding to selected row
var item = grid.dataItem(sel);
// Get the data that you are looking for
var ageDOB = item.Birthdate;
```

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/1wg8h46k/

The advantages of this solution are:

- If columns are hidden, reordered or you don't even know the order it keeps working.
- If the date is displayed using some format (as in my JSFiddle) what you get is the value stored and not the value displayed.

Comment: its failing on debug. it keeps returning as undefined.

Comment: ok I got it to come back as a date but format is messed up cause its not comparing accurately with the other two date values that i have in the function

Comment: So, is it working or not? On which format do you need the date?

Comment: I have two date values being pulled from a database that return a values in the following format "7/1/1994 12:00:00 AM"
but the ageDOB returns a value in a format that looks like this: Sun Jun 25 1995 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
I need to be able to compare ageDOB and see if it falls between the other two dates but in my test even though the actual date is correctly between them it comes back false instead of true

Comment: I realize now I should most likely do this as a new question so i will create a new question regarding the formatting issue.

Comment: the new question is here
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391315/pulling-kendo-ui-grid-selected-item-date-value-but-the-result-is-in-the-wrong-fo)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

If your grid column is static then do this,

```
var grid = $( "#MainRosterGrid" ).data( "kendoGrid" );
var selectedRows = grid.select();
var value = $(selectedRows).find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

`.find('td:eq(2)')` hrre `2` is column index.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mgdnE/166/